# Is there a modern way to run java applications in browser?

Tags: java, applet, java-web-start

Is there a **modern** way to run java application on the web? As far as I know, java applets and java web start both are deprecated.

I have an android app, written in java, which I want to run on server (of course, altered in some way). While java is cross-platform there is no problem to transfer it to desktop (no matter, javafx, swing or etc.).

Apparently, it would be great not to re-write it in some other language.

Comment: There are JSP / Servlets and there is GWT.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nowadays, we're using GWT at work. Well.. It's efficient, it's fast and compatible with all browsers. And it's so easy to build a web page with GWT. You can check tutorials from this [link](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/tutorial/index.html).

And you can look up for Spring MVC. Not the most flexible choice for UI, I know. But give it a shot. [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html)

But.. If you're open to new things, I'll totally recommend React Js. It's flexible,it's super fast with perfect UI. If you ever think of using Java just for back end, React js is a great deal for UI. [link](https://reactjs.org/)

Comment: Since you are using android I think GWT is the right choice.
The Inbox app from Google is written largely in GWT so a lot of code is re-used between Android and the webapp.

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays you should be able to run Java (and most other languages) in the browser throught WebAssembly (Wasm).

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68265863/how-to-compile-java-to-wasm-webassembly) recommends [TeaVM](https://teavm.org).

There also is [Bytecoder](https://github.com/mirkosertic/Bytecoder).

Answer (score 0):

There is an HelloWorld Example Java-Program which is running in a browser:

https://github.com/neo-expert/jsjvm_helloworld

After compiling you can just run the jar file which starts a webserver where the program will be served. (port 8080)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible and I can guarantee if you follow this tutorial you will be shocked about how super easy is to use  the Java Virtual Machine for modern web browsers which called [`CheerpJ`](https://labs.leaningtech.com/cheerpj3).

CheerpJ is a WebAssembly-based Java Virtual Machine for the browser. It has extensive compatibility with Java 8 and provides a full runtime environment1 for running Java applications, applets, libraries, and Java Web Start / JNLP applications in the browser without plugins.

Here is a super easy example on JS run this:

```
<script src="https://cjrtnc.leaningtech.com/3.0rc2/cj3loader.js"></script>
await cheerpjInit();
const lib = await cheerpjRunLibrary("/app/example.jar");

const Example = await lib.com.example.Example;
const example = await new Example();
await example.hello();
```

And this is the Java method call:

```
package com.example;

public class Example {
  public String[] greetings = {"Hello", "Bye"};
  public void hello() {
    System.out.println("Example says hello!");
  }
}
```

**Attention!!!** the app is not a folder path in your project but instead, it refers to the root of web server for example app=http://localhost:8080/ for more info refer to this [link](https://labs.leaningtech.com/cheerpj3/guides/File-System-support)